# ERROR blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:671 - Connection issue in R

Tags: r, api, bloomberg

Currently following instructions from `rblpapi-intro.Rmd` (version date: 2015-08-13) I am wondering why:

```
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()
```

returns:

```
17FEB2016_14:27:17.296 7432:8884 ERROR  
blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:671 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{3}.
<localhost:8194> Connection failed 
17FEB2016_14:27:17.296 7432:8884 WARN blpapi_platformcontroller.cpp:371 
blpapi.session.platformcontroller.{3} Platform: 0 failed 1 consecutive  
connect attempts, stopped trying to reconnect. 
Error: Failed to start session.
```

given the below default values:

```
ip: 127.0.0.1
port: 8194
```

Factually, there is nothing wrong with those values as I've used them in `Matlab` using `con=blp(port,ip2,time)` and the connection succeeds perfectly.

**EDIT**:

The below function has finally worked! a bit `weird`, as I override the default ip value from `blpConnect()` by the same value.

```
blpConnect(host = getOption("blpHost", "127.0.0.1"),
           port = getOption("blpPort", 8194L), default = TRUE)
```

Thus it looks like `blpConnect()` did'nt pointed to the default `ip` and port values for some reasons.